# Most Commonly-Adopted Calculus Textbooks

Tags: calculus, textbooks, usa

I am looking for an article (or other source) that addresses the calculus textbook industry, specifically which calculus textbooks are most commonly adopted. I'm primarily interested in that of the U.S.

I've heard that Stewart's calculus texts dominate approximate 2/5 of the calculus textbook market, but I'm looking for a source that supports such a claim (and also discusses the performance of other texts (e.g., Thomas) in the calculus textbook market).

Comment: Are you interested in the international market, or just that of a particular country?

Comment: I'm primarily interested in that of the U.S.

Comment: Are you asking in terms of quality or finances ?

Comment: Maybe not definitive, but sales-rank on Amazon should be highly correlated with it.

Comment: What level calculus? High school non-AP calc, high school AP calc, college calc for non-STE majors, college calc for STE majors, college calc for math majors? High school non-AP calc will be the most watered down and procedural, college calc for math majors will be the most theoretical, and the rest will be on the spectrum in between.

Comment: Amazon sales figures might be polluted with sales to homeschoolers and those who are dissatisfied with the texts adopted by their schools. I know people who purchase math books from the mid-20th century because they consider the recent ones badly written.

Comment: @shoover: I'm interested in single-variable calculus for undergraduates, primarily for science and engineering majors but also for math majors. 

I am aware of the differences between texts. I'm only interested in finding a source which gives data regarding which calculus texts are most commonly adopted for university-level single-variable calculus.

Comment: Somewhere I asked an equivalent question about college algebra books, and it similarly went nowhere.

Comment: Have you looked at amazon sales ranks?

Answer (score 3):

As a rough start, I get this from Amazon...
[image: authors]

Comment: Could you tell us more precisely how you got that graphic / list? That does not quite agree with what I get when I look at the bestsellers list under Books > Textbooks > Science & Mathematics > Mathematics > Calculus.

Comment: @RoryDaulton ... Go ahead and post what you got. This one is  **Books : Science & Math : Mathematics : Pure Mathematics : Calculus**, then look at the authors in the left column.  I had tried calculus bestsellers, but it seems biology and chemistry books are at the top of that...

Comment: I have upvoted your answer, but removing duplicate authors I get this top-20 list starting with #1: David E. Bock, James Stewart, Ron Larson, Jon Rogawski, Michael Sullivan, Deborah Hughes-Hallett, William L. Briggs, Ross L. Finney, Soo T. Tan, Frank Ayres, Karl J. Smith, Raymond A. Barnett. Stewart is not #1 but he does have #2,3,4,5,8,11, and 14. One could argue that Bock is not a textbook, since it is advertised as a "comprehensive AP test preparation manual."